# Notepad++ regular expression search

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a log file where summary will have 0 Error(s) or X Error(s).

I tried to find Errors other than 0 Error(s).

I tried with this option in Regular expression but it does no good. `\ [^0] Error(s)`

Am I missing anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this here

```
 [1-9][0-9]* Error\(s\)
```

You don't need to escape spaces, but you need to escape brackets, if you want to match them literally. And be careful with `[^0]`, it will match anything but a 0 (e.g. akÖ{@), not only other digits.

This expression will also match numbers with more than one digit.

Comment: I don't think »@ Errors« will be a likely occurrence. :-)

Comment: @Joey, do you know how his logfile looks like? You never know ;-).

Comment: will your solution work for more than 2 digit too? some times errors may be more than 2 digits

Comment: Yes it will, The first digit is matched by `[1-9]` and this `[0-9]*` means match 0 or more digits.